# How to select row in grid AFTER load grid?

Tags: extjs

Model.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0) not work ...

Comment: not work!???? why not work?

Comment: Show more code (especially how you're triggering the line above). Are there any error messages in error console?

Comment: selectRow() is actual for ExtJs v.3 It is deprecated in v4. As @Danny mentioned .getSelectionModel().select(0) is actual for newest versions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
    ...
    listeners: {
        load: function() {
            this.grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
        },
        scope: this
    }
});

this.grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ...
    store: this.store
});
```

Something like this should work, assuming this.store and this.grid exist, I'm sure you can adapt it.

Comment: Why should there be a grid in the store object? Usually it's the other way round.

Comment: Because the load event is fired from the store not the grid. I'm not saying Store has a grid property either, infact you have to specifically have your own references in `this` in order for this to work but he should have that anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

I am just reiterating Lioyd's answer. 
Also make sure that you have configured RowSelection Model in grid.

```
var grid  = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
              store: ....,
              sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),

              // other grid configurations goes here
              listeners: {
                render : function(grid){
                  grid.store.on('load', function(store, records, options){
                    grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();       
                  });                      
                }
               }
            })
```

Comment: Your might have some scoping issues and redundancy here.

Comment: grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);

Comment: @Danny: Your code line works - Thanks